# Auto fill np.nan for arrays of different size

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to pass a dictionary of items into Dataframe, but these items can have variable length arrays. What is the most elegant way to append np.nan to the arrays so that they match the sizes?
For example:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[1,2], "c":[1]})
```

should return me

```
a  b  c
1  1  1
2  2  nan
3  nan  nan
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe:

```
d = {"a":[1,2,3],"b":[1,2], "c":[1]}
pd.concat(map(pd.Series, d.values()), keys=d.keys(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
d = {"a":[1,2,3],"b":[1,2], "c":[1]}
pd.DataFrame({x:pd.Series(d[x]) for x in d})
```